# How do I enumerate supported scaling modes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to be able to to enumerate the supported scaling modes of a graphics adapter in C++, targeting Windows XP.

I referred to the online documentation of the closest appropriate function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611(v=vs.85).aspx `EnumDisplaySettings` but it says it only populates the following fields:

- dmBitsPerPel
- dmPelsWidth
- dmPelsHeight
- dmDisplayFlags
- dmDisplayFrequency

So how do I enumerate supported `dmDisplayFixedOutput` values of the `DEVMODE` struct?